# How to change AAD Edition (pricing tier)?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I had upgraded the Basic AAD to Premium P2 by starting a free trial. How do I downgrade back to Basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not upgrade or downgrade an Azure AD tenant. The licenses (Basic, P1, P2, Standalone MFA, etc.) are **per-user** licences. Each purchased license can be assigned to exactly one user object or not assigned at all. Check [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/working-with-licenses?view=azureadps-2.0) for more info. You can also use group based licensing to license users based on their group memberships.

When you activate free trial, you become 100 (I believe it was 100) respective licenses, which you can assign to your users. Once the trial is over, you no longer have the respective licenses, so your users are not licensed anymore. The only thing you can do is to remove the license assignment of the expired licenses. Which will effectively "`downgrade`" your users.

If you had Azure AD Basic licenses before, you have to do nothing. But if you hadn't, and you would like to purchase Basic, you can do so. Just purchase Azure AD Basic licenses (the amount you need to cover your users) and assign those to the users.

If you want to immediately stop using P2 - just remove the P2 assignments and forget about them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot down it directly. But you can buy Basic AAD when the Premium P2 expires.